# How do I get 'distroy'?

Tags: cities-skylines

At this point, I have many, many districts and I've tried individualizing the policies in each:

[image]

Steam simply does not seem to acknowledge that each of my districts are, in fact, very different snowflakes. Is there something I'm missing in the acquisition of this achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much information I could gather, you need 10 districts, each with unique policies.

I would also disable all "city wide" policies for that moment when you give every district just **one** policy.

Comment: Yeah, it seems information on the game is rather sparse at the moment. It's very difficult to ascertain some of the achievement requirements :( -- This worked, though. Disabling city-wide policies was a good idea.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, it seems like kind of a silly achievement. If you have you disable a bunch of city-wide policies, it will almost never happen organically.